# Full text search with a very simple MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I recently came across a wierd issue with MySQL Fulltext search. My statement is really simple:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE MATCH (`desc`) AGAINST ('+NOR +710' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

And this is what in the `desc` column: "The NOR 710 also has smoke seal ..."

For some reason it won't find that row. I added Fulltext index to that column, mysql version is 5.1.56 , database engine of that table is MyISAM. Is there anything else i need to check?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, fulltext indexes [will ignore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) words that are shorter than 4 charaters. Adjust your `ft_min_word_len` to also include the shorter words.

Comment: Thanks very much, it was exactly what i need. You're a start :)

Comment: @locdinh: No problem, glad I could help! The best way to thank me by the way is marking my answer as accepted. ;)